# Maintaining the consistency of strings before and after converting to ASCII

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7, unicode, consistency

I have many strings in unicode format such as *carbon copolymers—III\n12- Géotechnique\n* and many more having many different unicode characters, in a string variable named **txtWords**.

My goal is to remove all non-ASCII characters **while preserving** the consistency of the strings. For instance I want to first sentence turn into *carbon copolymers III* or **carbon copolymers iii** (no case-sensitivity here) and the second one to *geotechnique\n* and so on ...

Currently I am using the following code but it doesn't help me achieve what I expect. The current code changes *carbon copolymers III* to **carbon copolymersiii** which is definitely not what it should be:

```
import unicodedata, re
txtWords = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', txtWords.lower()).encode('ascii','ignore')
txtWords = re.sub(r'[^a-z^\n]',r' ',txtWords)
```

If I use the regex code first then I get something worse (in terms of what I expect):

```
    import unicodedata, re
    txtWords = re.sub(r'[^a-z^\n]',r' ',txtWords)
    txtWords = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', txtWords.lower()).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

This way, for the string **Géotechnique\n** I get **otechnique**!

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: See Unidecode: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/

Comment: This depends on why you need that reduction to ASCII. For your regex to be useful, you have to first apply the regex and then encode to ASCII

Comment: @roeland Well if I apply regex first then I get something even worse: **Géotechnique\n** will become **otechnique**

Comment: @roeland And well I need that reduction since I'm matching those words with a ASCII-based words data base that I have.

Comment: @Amir That's not what I meant. I was talking about the `.encode('ascii','ignore')` call. This call strips away non-ascii characters like the en-dash (—). So apply that call last. I'm guessing you got that code fragment [here](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/unicode-to-ascii). So I think you need to pause for a second and understand what each of these calls do.

Comment: You could apply the regex first by targeting just the characters you're interested in. Positive class is `[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-@\[-\`{-\x7f]` negative class is `[^a-zA-Z\x{80}-\x{10ffff}\r\n]` both do the same thing.

Comment: @Amir You shouldn't change the title to resolved. Accepting an answer should suffice. More info in the meta post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285390/5290909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\w` regular expression to strip non-alphanumerics before the decomposing trick:

```
#coding:utf8
from __future__ import unicode_literals,print_function
import unicodedata as ud
import re
txtWords = 'carbon copolymers—III\n12- Géotechnique\n'
txtWords = re.sub(r'[^\w\n]',r' ',txtWords.lower(),flags=re.U)
txtWords = ud.normalize('NFKD',txtWords).encode('ascii','ignore').decode()
print(txtWords)
```

Output (Python 2 and 3):

```
carbon copolymers iii
12  geotechnique
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Are you sure this is the correct code?
After I execute     txtWords = re.sub(r'[^\w\n]',r' ',txtWords.lower()) I get **'carbon copolymers   iii\n12  g  otechnique\n'**

Comment: @Amir, you didn't specify a Python version.  I was using Python 3.  Updated to work in both.  `txtWords` needs to be a Unicode string to start with, and for `\w` to work correctly in Python 2, `flags=re.U` is required for the `re.sub`.

Comment: @Amir, the code was correct so I rolled back your edit. The `from __future__ import unicode_literals` handles that and is portable to Python 3.

Comment: Well if you don't convert the string to unicode in the first place, then the normalization code does not work (at least for me)

Comment: @Amir, it *is* Unicode if you have `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.  You can also just make it a Unicode string without it by using `u'carbon...'`.  You may need it in your code if you don't have that, but it isn't needed in mine.  In fact, your edit gives an error in Python 2 of `decoding Unicode not supported`.

Comment: Can you please take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034225/remove-unicode-symbols-while-preserving-string-consistency)?